# The Little ML'er - Good training for F#?

Tags: f#, ocaml, ml

I want to get up to speed on F# and was wondering if the book "The Little ML'er" would be of help since F# is based on OCaml which is a derivative of ML. Or, Is ML too different from F# to be of any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read it without typing in the examples, it will familiarize you with the core concepts. But OCaml's syntax that F# borrows is different enough that half the examples won't work without (trivial) changes.

This said, in my memory, "The little MLer" is very basic and more aimed at someone who knows no programming language at all.